# testing using Babel,Bluebird Promises and Mocha runs tests in wrong order

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, bluebird, es6-promise

I am a bit confused and I am also a newcomer to promises.
My problem is that the beforeEach function runs in random order (how is this possible?) so that the delete query is not run first. Also the order changes if I put console.log messages in the promise (??). What am I doing wrong here.

Note that the database (neo4j in this case) returns 200 OK in case there is a constrain violation that is why I am reading the result and then rejecting.

I have this test (using chai-as-promised):

```
    beforeEach(function() {

    return neodb.query('MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r',{}) //clear the db first
        .then(neodb.query(query,{props:[{username:'arisAlexis'}]}))
        .then(neodb.query(query,{props:[{username:'marySilva'}]}))
        .then(neodb.query(query,{props:[{username:'silviaBurakof'}]}));

});

it('create a username conflict',function() {
    return User.create([{username:'arisAlexis'}]).should.be.rejected;
})
```

User.create is a static method that just runs this :

```
return db.query(query,{props:props});
```

so it returns a promise that is created here:

```
exports.query=function(query,params) {

return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    request.postAsync({
        uri: dbUrl,
        json: {statements: [{statement: query, parameters: params}]}
    }).then(function(result) {
        if (result[1].errors.length > 0) {
            reject(new NeoError(result[1].errors[0].message,result[1].errors[0].code));
        }
        resolve(result[1].results);

    });
});}
```

I am running mocha with babel-node.
I am also using promisify on request module and I am rejecting with a custom error (am I using it correctly ? In the documentation they throw the error).

Comment: your promise creation is the explicit construction anti-pattern, you can return from a `then` instead of using the promise constructor explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing all query functions at the same time, instead of waiting for the previous one to end:

```
.then(neodb.query(...)) // this executes `neodb.query()` right away
                        // and uses its return value as the callback
                        // function for the `.then()`.
```

Here's how to fix that:

```
beforeEach(function() {

  return neodb.query('MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r',{}).then(function() {
    return neodb.query(query,{props:[{username:'arisAlexis'}]});
  }).then(function() {
    return neodb.query(query,{props:[{username:'marySilva'}]});
  }).then(function() {
    return neodb.query(query,{props:[{username:'silviaBurakof'}]});
  });

});
```